# Question about continuous from right or left

Tags: calculus, continuity

I saw the claim that say:
"Suppose that g is continuous at $x_0$; $g\left(x_0\right)$ is an interior point of $D_f$ ;
and f is continuous at $g\left(x_0\right)$: Then $\left(f\:\circ \:g\right)$ is continuous at $x_0$."

It is true to say that ? :
"Suppose that g is continuous **from right** at $x_0$; $g\left(x_0\right)$ is an interior point of $D_f$ ;
and f is continuous **from right** at $g\left(x_0\right)$, Then $\left(f\:\circ \:g\right)$ is continuous **from right** at $x_0$."

If it does, can someone show me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. Consider $$f\colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R, \quad f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{for $x < 0$} \\ 1 & \text{for $x \geq 0$} \end{cases}$$ and $$g\colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R, \quad g(x) = -x.$$
Then $f$ is continuous from the right at $x_0 = 0$, $g$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$ but $f \circ g$ is not continous from the right at $x_0$. The problem is, as you can see in this example, that $g$ can change the "direction" of your sequence approaching $x_0$.

You can fix this problem by requiring $g$ to be monotonic increasing: In this case pick a sequence $(x_n)$, $x_n \to x_0$ with $x_n \geq x_0$. Then $g(x_n) \to g(x_0)$ and because $g$ is monotonic increasing there also holds $g(x_n) \geq g(x_0)$ and therefore you can use the right-continuity of $f$ at $g(x_0)$.

Answer (score 0):

It is false.  For an example, think of a function which is piecewise linear and which is left-continuous at your point, but that segment has a negative slope.